# Helmet expects a string as a child of <head>. Did you forget to wrap your children in braces

Tags: reactjs

Hi I know this is probably a stupid question but what does this error mean in relation to my `app.js` file? It didn't appear until I ran my local server. Was working fine prior.

```
Error: Helmet expects a string as a child of <head>. Did you forget to wrap your children in braces? ( <head>{``}</head> ) Refer to our API for more information.
```

#### What it's pointing at is this specific line of code in my `App.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Is it pointing to the pages I've made and an improper `Helmet` element? I've been browsing through the code trying to figure this one out. Any help or insight is appreciated.

#### Edit~Here is my homepage:

```js
import React from "react";  
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import {Carousel} from 'react-bootstrap';                                                        
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import slide1 from "../images/websliders1.png";
import slide2 from "../images/websliders2.png";
import slide3 from "../images/websliders3.png";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import "../components/scss/index.scss";

const Home = () => {
    return(
        <div style={{ width: `100%`, marginBottom: `0`, height:'auto', overflow:'hidden', zIndex:'1'}}>
            <Layout>
                <Helmet>
                    <head>
                        <title> Home | BradGradGraphics</title>
                        <meta property="og:description" content="Freelancing service that offers graphic design, illustration, and some small web design work digitally" />
                        <meta property="og:url"   content="https://bradgrad.graphics" />
                        <meta property="og:type"  content="website" />
                        <meta property="og:title" content="BradGradGraphics" />
                        <meta property="og:image" content="../images/SplashPgConc.png" />
                    </head>
                </Helmet>
                <Carousel >
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <Link to='/gallery'>
                            <img className="d-block w-100 img-responsive"
                            src={slide1}
                            alt="First Slide"
                            
                            />
                            
                            <Carousel.Caption>
                                <h1 style={{color:'black'}}>My Illustrations</h1>
                                <p style={{color:'black'}}>Check them out!</p>
                            </Carousel.Caption>
                        </Link>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <a href='https://blog.bradgrad.graphics/'>
                            <img className="d-block w-100"
                            src={slide2}
                            alt="Second Slide"
                            />
                            
                            <Carousel.Caption>
                                <h1 style={{color:'black'}}>Blog</h1>
                                <p style={{color:'black'}}>Give it a read!</p>
                            </Carousel.Caption>
                         </a>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        {/* <Link to='#'> */}
                            <img className="d-block w-100"
                            src={slide3}
                            alt="Third Slide"
                            />
                            <Carousel.Caption>
                                <h1 style={{color:'black'}}>Comics Incoming!</h1>
                                <p style={{color:'black'}}>Stay Tuned!</p>
                            </Carousel.Caption>
                        {/* </Link> */}
                    </Carousel.Item>
                </Carousel>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Home;
```

Comment: Could you provide the file where you use `<Helmet/>`?

Comment: @RyanLe, just added the update

Comment: @BradG. , Example of ```react-helmet``` : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-helmet-basic-example-forked-70fi6

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @RyanLe, it did! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have a `<head>` inside your `<Helmet>` as it already did for you

So remove the `<head>` tag:

```
<Helmet>
  <title> Home | BradGradGraphics</title>
  <meta
    property="og:description"
    content="Freelancing service that offers graphic design, illustration, and some small web design work digitally"
  />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://bradgrad.graphics" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="BradGradGraphics" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="../images/SplashPgConc.png" />
</Helmet>;
```